# Why isn't $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \left[ \frac px \right] = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find $L$ 
>   $$\lim_{x\to{0^+}}  x\left(\left[\frac 1x\right] + \left[\frac 2x\right] + \left[\frac 3x\right] + \cdots + \left[\frac {12}x\right]\right) = L$$
>   Here $[t]$ represents the greatest integer less than or equal to $t$.

Now since $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \left[ \dfrac px \right] = \lim_{x \to 0^+} x\left( \frac px - \left\{\frac p x\right\}\right) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \left(p-x \left\{\frac px\right\}\right) = p$$

I get $L=1+2+3 +\cdots + 12 = 120$. This would seem fine.

*Here's what confuses me:*

$x$ is a really small positive number. So $\frac 1x$ would be an incredibly large number. So $[\frac 1x]$ would also be large. Now we multiply it with $x$ which is effectively zero. So $x \times [\frac 1x]$ should be zero. And subsequently $L$ should be zero.

So it boils down to the following:
Why isn't $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \left[ \dfrac px \right] = 0$ ? When all we're doing is multiplying zero with a very large number to yield zero.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe removing the floor would clarify this: $1/x$ is very large and $x$ is effectively zero, yet their product is not close to zero.

Comment: "x is a really small positive number. So 1/x
would be an incredibly large number. So  [1/x would also be large. Now we multiply it with x which is effectively zero. So x×[1x],should be zero. And subsequently L should be zero."   NO, that is simply not true.  For example if x= 0.0001, then 1/x= 10000 which is an integer.  x[1/x]= 0.0001(10000)= 1.

Comment: "effectively zero" and "zero" are very different things. "effectively zero" can become strictly positive, or even infinite, if it's multiplied by something sufficiently large. The thing you're multiplying by is sufficiently large.

Comment: @Wojowu But it makes no intuitive sense: Integer $\times$ Zero $=$ Zero. , right?

Comment: The thing is that $x$ is _not_ exactly zero. You should similarly argue that $1/x$ is "effectively infinity", and infinity times a positive real number gives infinity, right? Turns out that the very large $1/x$ and very small $x$ "balance" each other just right so that their product is neither very large nor very small.

Comment: @Wojowu The mist of confusion is lifting. thanks

Comment: Interestingly, you give a correct proof of the limit, yet you don't believe this proof. And there is no doubt that $xp/x$ should tend to $p$, is it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The think that bothered me was that I kept getting two answers :P

Comment: @SmarthBansal: what I mean is that the explanation of the flaw in your second reasoning is quite visible in the first reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When all we're doing is multiplying zero with a very large number to yield zero.

No, that's not what we're doing.

$x$ is *not* zero in that expression, any more than ${p\over x}$ is $\infty$ (let's ignore the "$[]$" for now). If we imagine setting $x$ to be literally zero, then we would looking at $$0\cdot {p\over 0}=0\cdot\infty.$$ Note how the "$p\over x$" part *also* did something extreme, with the result that the "value" we get is **completely meaningless**. In general, we can't compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ by just thinking about $f(a)$, and this is an example of that.

Your confusion arises because you're thinking of the first $x$ in "$x\cdot [{p\over x}]$" as actually being $0$ but you're not thinking of the second $x$ as actually being $0$. Indeed, *neither* of the $x$s is actually zero: when evaluating the expression "$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}x\cdot[{p\over x}]$," we're looking at positive *but nonzero* $x$ (look back at the precise definition of a limit).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. Right on spot.

Answer (score 1):

Your "So $\dfrac 1x$ would be an incredibly large number" is contradictory with "we multiply it with $x$ which is effectively zero".

If $\dfrac 1x$ would be an incredibly large number, then $x$ would be an incredibly small number, and their product... $1$.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer!